# two sided ks test loop, get p.value

Tags: r, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have a column of data from which I am taking randomized sub samples of 50%.
I'm running a two sided ks test to compare the distribution of `50%` of the data against 100% of the data to see if the distribution is still a significant fit.

In order to meet my objectives I want to run this as a loop of say 1000 to get an average p-value from 1000 randomized sub samples. This line of code gives me a single p-value for a random subset of 50% of my sample:

```
dat50=dat[sample(nrow(dat),replace=F,size=0.50*nrow(dat)),]
ks.test(dat[,1],dat50[,1], alternative="two.sided")
```

I need a line of code that will run this 1000 times saving the resulting (different) p value each time in a column which I can then average. The code I'm trying to get to work looks like this:

```
x <- numeric(100)
for (i in 1:100){
  x<- ks.test(dat[,7],dat50[,7], alternative="two.sided")
  x<-x$p.value
}
```

However this does not store multiple p-values

Also tried this:

```
get.p.value <- function(df1, df2) {
  x <- rf(5, df1=df1, df2=df2)
  p.value <- ks.test(dat[,6],dat50[,6], alternative="two.sided")$p.value
}
replicate (2000, get.p.value(df1 = 5, df2 = 10))
```

I hope that is clear and I would appreciate any help solving this so much!

Q

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You know the subsample was drawn from the full variable, so you know the null is true. Why are you doing this? What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I'm comparing the representativeness of sampling strategies, I have a dataset of 137 samples from one method and my question is how many samples would be required to meet the same representativeness statistically by random sampling. Because the spatial coverage of the full dataset is very good there is no need to resample because I can take a random subset. The distributions of my variables are not normal so I think I can determine whether a 50% subsample is representative of the distribution of the full sample by using a two sided ks test.

Comment: *reply continued*
only problem is, that a random subset of 50% of the sample can give me a p value anywhere between 0.5 and 1 depending on how many times I take the random subsample. To solve this I thought I could take the p values from the randomisation 1000 times and average the result. Just haven't quite learned r well enough to build the code.

Hope that explains it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop you are overwriting `x` in each iteration meaning that you will only save the p-value for the last iteration. Try this instead:

```
x <- numeric(100)
for (i in 1:length(x))
    x[i] <- ks.test(dat[,17], dat[sample(nrow(dat), replace=F, size=0.5*nrow(dat)),7])$p.value
```

You can get the same result using `replicate` with:

```
 replicate(100, ks.test(dat[,7], dat[sample(nrow(dat), replace=F, size=0.5*nrow(dat)),7])$p.value)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The first line seems to have worked!

Comment: The 'replicate' code seems to come up with: Error in data[sample(nrow(dat), replace = F, size = 0.5 * nrow(dat)),  : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Also I'm not sure where to find the p-values for this one. I can recall them in the first code by just running 'x'.

The first code works a dream though so thanks again!

Comment: Fixed a typo in the ```replicate``` example.

Comment: Ah I didn't spot that. Thanks again!